# WebStorm won't display project folders

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

As seen below in the picture, when I 'open folder' of a project I am developing, WebStorm doesn't display the folders in the projects window, only the files:

[image]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any chance they're excluded? Try switching from "Project" view to "Project Files" (above .babelrc)

Comment: or in settings (small rugged wheel thingy) check "show excluded files"

Comment: @timenomad results in an empty pane with the text 'Nothing to show'

Comment: @VladimirM Already selected :/

Comment: 1) Please show full list of all custom plugins that you have installed 2) If you close IDE; go to project folder and delete `.idea` subfolder (this project settings) and then use `Open` and point to the project root folder (IDE will create project from those files) -- in other words -- re-create project from scratch. Will it behave any differently?

Comment: @LazyOne no luck with this method, I do have IdeaVIM emulation plugin installed and otherwise nothing. I recently tried to install Team Foundation Server VCS plugin, perhaps this broke something because afterwards it seems the problem has appeared across any folder opened in the IDE. I did uninstall TFSVCS since.

Comment: In such case I suggest to backup and delete IDE-wide settings and start from scratch. If it will help .. then you may restore most of the settings from a backup. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 4):

Delete caches and .idea folder. Then restart your IDE. .idea folder will be recreated.

Comment: 'caches'? Where is that?

Comment: @Rice On the main menu, **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

Comment: still no luck with the above solution, the .idea folder is indeed re-created after cache clear/restart however the problem persists

Comment: @Rice Is this problem only this project or for all projects?

Comment: all projects/any folder that I try to open as a project

Answer (score 1):

1. WebStorm > Preferences > Directories > "+ Add Content Root" > [root
   dir] > Apply
2. If still not showing:

   - At top of Project panel, if dropdown is set to anything other than "Project" (e.g., "Default"), switch it to Project.